# Color Picker error in the console

Tags: error, console

We are getting the `Color-Picker error` in the console randomly. We don't know where it's coming from. We have read several posts but not got a satisfied answer.

Below is the screenshot for your reference:

[image]

Herewith I attached the script. Please have a look at it.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you share your script.js code, where you are facing error

Comment: please share your js code here

Comment: The thing is we are getting this error randomly when using the admin panel. So we are not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: Also, the screenshot which I have attached was from our client. So we haven't know the exact path to the file where the error comes from.

Comment: Please upload your file code here.

Comment: Verify your code with my answer. Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: @Magentovsmarttec this error comes due to the js file in js file just check  that function  exist or not verify the function name with your function name which you are calling in your phtml file if still not solved check that you are calling a right js file or not

Answer (score 1):

**Add JavaScript color picker library in your layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Create system.xml**

```
<config ...>
    <system>
        ...
        <section>
            ...
            <group id="my_color_group" ...>
                <field id="my_color_option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>abc\Color\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Create the block file:**

```
<?php
namespace abc\Color\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $elementId = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    $elementId.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $elementId.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add Colorpicker `js` And `css` in your layout file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with core file https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17008. Please make the following changes and it will disappear.

Navigate to your Magento Root Directory

Open the file lib/web/jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js

Find the below lines in your code nearby line no 10

```
define([
"jquery", ], function ($) { 
var ColorPicker = function () {
```

Change the line `define([` to `define("mage/colorpicker", [` so your code will look like

```
define("mage/colorpicker", [
    "jquery",
], function ($) {
    var ColorPicker = function () {
```

Font: [Magento 2.2.3 - How to fix ColorPicker issue in admin configuration?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281990/magento-2-2-3-how-to-fix-colorpicker-issue-in-admin-configuration)