# Magento 2.2.3 - How to fix ColorPicker issue in admin configuration?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, admin-panel, console, magento2.3.2

[image]My admin store was working correctly search on google 
and follow this question [created file as given](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265202/color-picker-error-in-the-console?rq=1) but still problem is exist

if any developer can explain what i am doing wrong ?? in the above link some pls describe the above related procedure

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: The thing is we are getting this error randomly when using the store configuration . So we are not sure where it's coming from

Comment: check the `var/log/` files

Comment: @JunaidKhan Have you customized any anything ?

Comment: No just installed cc-venue module

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with core file https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17008. Please make the following changes and it will disappear.

1. Navigate to your Magento Root Directory
2. Open the file **`lib/web/jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js`**
3. Find the below lines in your code nearby line no 10

   `define([
   "jquery", ], function ($) { 
   var ColorPicker = function () {`
4. Change the line `define([` to `define("mage/colorpicker", [` so your code will look like

   `define("mage/colorpicker", [
       "jquery",
   ], function ($) {
       var ColorPicker = function () {`

Comment: Thanks brother one error has been solved the other undefned function is still exist can help with that also is there way to know the file structure of your magento store

Comment: Can you post that error

Comment: https://imgur.com/FpKHxsS    u can see the image for error

Comment: Is the color picker function is used in any third-party modules or your own module

Comment: third party modules

Comment: Please add the <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head> in layout file of  your module which uses color picker function and let me know

Comment: The thing is we are getting this error randomly when using the store configuration . So we are not sure where it's coming from

Comment: If this does error occur randomly try static-content deploy with necessary permissions and check it